# Normal distribution of random numbers hangs the program?

Tags: c++, random, c++11

When I run this code is just hangs in for loop, can you explan why?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<random>
#include<ctime>

int main()
{
    using std::cout;
    using std::endl;
    using std::cin;
    using std::mt19937;
    using std::minstd_rand;
    using std::uniform_int;
    using std::normal_distribution;

    // engines
    mt19937 rng;
    minstd_rand gen;

    // distributions
    uniform_int<int> dist(0, 37);
    normal_distribution<short> norm(4, 3);

    // initializaiton
    rng.seed(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(false)));
    gen.seed(static_cast<unsigned short>(time(false)));



    // generate numbers
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        std::cout << dist(rng) << "     " << norm(gen) << endl; // This is as far as this code goes

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`std::uniform_int` is not C++11. You should use `std::uniform_int_distribution`. And `std::normal_distribution<T>` requires `T` to be floating point type (C++11 standard 26.5.8.5.1).

In fact, if you have gcc >= 4.5 you should get an error saying something like:

```
/opt/local/include/gcc47/c++/bits/random.h: In instantiation of 'class std::normal_distribution<short int>':
my_random.cpp:21:36:   required from here
/opt/local/include/gcc47/c++/bits/random.h:1982:7: error: static assertion failed: template argument not a floating point type
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I wasn't able to find some reference to std::random. cheers. Stil I have more questions but I'll open new topic since it's different :)

Answer (score 0):

It works for me.

These functions could be trying to source random data from `/dev/random`, which blocks if no high-quality random data is available. I've noticed this is quite common on cheap VPS hosting providers.

**Edit:** Perhaps it will help if we share details of our dev environments. Works for me on:

- Ubuntu 10.10
- g++ 4.4.5
- boost 1.40
- compiled with `g++ main.cpp -std=c++0x -o tst`

Answer (score 0):

I think I can guess. You are supposed to give the normal-distribution generator an engine that produces floating point numbers in the range 0..1. Instead, it is mistakenly being fed a diet of integers. A common algorithm for the normal distribution consumes those numbers in pairs, and loops until it finds a pair which, considered as point in 2-space, has a Cartesian norm that is less than one and not equal to zero. Since the algorithm is being fed nothing but integers, that never happens. But it never gives up.